# Is it safe to use constant x/y co-ordinates in iPhone production code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have used constant co-ordinates in code in several places in my iPhone app, particularly when I am programmatically creating a view, setting properties of uiview subclasses.

example:

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: img] autorelease];
imgView.center = CGPointMake(160, 175); // --> Are these constant usages safe?
[self.view addSubview: imgView];
```

I have tested it on simulator, device both 3G and 4S and it works.
Should I be worried for future device resolutions or any other gotchas?
If so, how should I make this piece of code, more safe? Any coding principles here?

Thanks
Mbh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a big deal in most cases, but it's always better to use a reference.

For example, if your image view is at the middle of the screen, you could use `screensize.width/2` instead of `160`, it's the same in theory, but first, it's more clear what you are doing, and second, if the screen were to change, you'd be prepared. Another example would be to use `navigationBar.frame.size.height` instead of `44` (which is not likely to change anyway).
Also, if you reference other views you laid yourself, and you move one, all of them will move with it ;).

In short, if you have a reference you can use, use it, otherwise, don't worry.

Comment: this is right, but just to point out that the iOS currently handles the translation between the different screen sizes automatically. i.e. you specify going to (160, 175) that is where it goes on the old phones and on the new phones it will automatically go to (320, 350). I assume if they add another new resolution at any point it will handle that as well, but as the answer says it is probably better to get a handle of something if you can.

Comment: Yes, but this (as well as the size of some UI elements) MIGHT change in the future. Chances are low, but it's better to be prepared. Also, if you want to port your code to the iPad, you'll have to change all your hardcoded values.

Comment: I agree. Just wanted to point out how the OS currently works as well. As for porting to the iPad, you are almost certainly not using the same values as you would on the iPhone. It needs to be redesigned and as such will have completely separate code anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe - You'll just need to know how the APIs you interact with will interpret the values in more detail. Is the space flipped? Do the APIs you call interpret that in points? Pixels? Cartesian coordinates? etc.